# How can I display my birth year in Facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

My birth year is not seen on my Facebook profile in timeline, at upper right.
How can do that ? I tried many things, added posts and changed their time to older time, my birthday time, but I couldn't do it.
I don't know if I have to use some FBML code for this.
Does anyone have a solution to this ?

**Edit :**
My birth day and year is visible to everyone.

Here is a screenshot :
In the image, "Doğdu" means born in Turkish.
[image]
In fact I have born in 1979 but
but here it seems as 2000.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is normal. Even if you have events the same year as your birth, there's just a line for "Born" (or, in your case, "Doğdu").

Here's a screen shot of mine:

[image: timeline decade list]

I was born before 1971.

So, click on *Doğdu* and you'll see your entry for when you were born.

Comment: I have an event to 1979 (as I have born in 1979), I have posted some things to 1979 also but still its not seen in these years. (Yes, 'Doğdu' means 'Born' in Turkish. What can I do other than this, to be able to display my birth year in these years ?

Comment: You can't. That's the way Facebook displays things.

Answer (score -1):

In your profile go to:

```
About -> Contact and Basic Info -> Birth Year
```

And it will have the option to edit or add your birth year, as well as select which of your FB contacts can see that information.

Comment: But I've already done before. Though I checked the visibility and its visible for everyone, already. What I'm missing ?

Answer (score -1):

Goto profile>About>Basic Information// And check if your birth year and birth date are not under "Only Me"

When you place your cursor hovering  about your Birth Date/Year, look at the right, if there is a Lock sign means only you can see it, if there is a Globe sign means everyone can see it e.c.t.

Comment: My birth day and year is visible to everyone.

Comment: Then in that case I'm not very sure...I'll tell you when I know!